# cant access information behind reference c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, function, reference, return

Trying to do a subtraction of two vectors. In the end it should work like:

```
vector1.sub(vector2);
```

Custom Variable Vektor was defined as: `Vektor(double x, double y, double z)`.
Now I want to access the `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates through `input.x`, etc.
Tells me

> ```
> conversion from 'Vektor*' to non scalar type 'Vektor' requested.
> ```

Why tough??? Is it not possible to subtract a reference on to a value from a value?

Btw im new to SO so feel free to roast me for whatever ive done wrong!;)

```
Vektor Vektor::sub(const Vektor& input) const
{
    Vektor subresult = new Vektor(x - input.x, y - input.y, z - input.z);
    return subresult;
}
```

Comment: The `new` returns a pointer, and is just not needed. C++ is not Java.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `new` here, just return by value

```
Vektor Vektor::sub(const Vektor& input) const
{
    return Vektor(x - input.x, y - input.y, z - input.z);
}
```

Also note that [you can override `operator-`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719) so you can perform a subtraction using the syntax `v1 - v2` where each are of type `Vektor`.